# Give an example of a $2×3$ matrix $A$ such that the solution set of the linear system $Ax=0$ is the plane $2x+3y-z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Give an example of a $2×3$ matrix $A$ such that the solution set of
>   the linear system $Ax=0$ is the plane $2x+3y-z=0$

I interpreted the question this way: 
$$ A \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z \\
        \end{pmatrix} = 0 $$

However, one such example of the $2×3$ matrix $A$ was said to be  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 3 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.

Now, putting the answer back into the above equation: 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 3 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0        \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z \\
        \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        2x+3y-z \\ 0        \end{pmatrix} $$

How is $ \begin{pmatrix}
        2x+3y-z \\ 0        \end{pmatrix} = 0 $?

Thanks.

Comment: What the hell is the last line?

Comment: @kennylau i've edited :)

Comment: When did anyone claim that to be true?

Comment: It's the answer given for this question. If it's not true, what's one example for the above question? @kennylau

Comment: It's true, and $\mathbf 0$ means $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ there

Comment: @KennyLau isit based on the fact the plane equation $ 2x+3y−z=0$?

Comment: Without even looking at the answer attempt, one can note that the multiplication of a $2\times3$ and a $3\times1$ matrix in the LHS of the equation WILL result in a **$2\times3$** matrix (with both elements $= 0$) in the RHS.